# The object invoked has disconnected from its clients Excel VBA (all of a sudden)

Tags: excel, vba

Lots of stuff out there about this issue, but none that fix my problem. Very simple.
When executing code (please see excerpt below) in a specific procedure, I get the above error. Excel then hangs. All I can do at that point is 'End Task' in Task Manager, Processes tab.

I've researched this for hours and tried many of the suggestions, but no joy. This was working for years. Now, all of a sudden, I'm experiencing this issue.

Thank you in advance.

The error occurs regardless of whether "ABC" is active / selected.

I've tried `Rows("1:4").Calculate` while on ABC, and get the same error

I'm able to recalc the entire sheet (Shift+F9) manually, `ActiveSheet.Calculate` works, `Sheets("ABC").calculate` works, `Sheets("ABC").Rows("1:4").Calculate` FAILS

Code:

```
...
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Sheets("ABC").Rows("1:4").Calculate 'FAILS HERE
```

...

Comment: Have you tried `Sheets("ABC").UsedRange.Rows("1:4").Calculate` ?  This will have it only use the appropriate column count for rows 1:4 (or you can define a range by cells), while not doing this for the full 16k columns available in excel.

Answer (score 0):

My $0.02...

Option 1:

```
Sheets("ABC").UsedRange.Rows("1:4").Calculate 'lets VBA determine last column
```

Option 2:

```
dim lc as long
with sheets("ABC")
    lc = .cells(1,.columns.count).end(xltoleft).column 'last column in first row, as used range MAY be further right
    .range(.cells(1,1),.cells(4,lc)).calculate 'specific range to calculate
end with
```

Comment: Thanks, Cyril. I'll give it a try and report back. In any event, your suggestions are much more efficient than my (lazy) coding. The fact that calculating the entire sheet works, leads me to believe this is just another excel bug. To make matters worse, the issue is intermittent - if I open a new book and code Sheets("Sheet1").Rows("1:4").calculate it works without issue.

Comment: Ok - both of your suggestions resulted in the same error. The only thing that seems to work is Sheets("ABC").Calculate. No valid reason, so I can only assume the workbook is somehow corrupted - unfortunately moving everything over to a new workbook would be slightly more difficult than launching a 3rd world war, so...

Comment: For the sake of trouble shooting, have you tried moving some of the data to a new workbook to see if that doesn't cause any issues?

Comment: Thanks again, Cyril. I've already determined there's nothing inherently wrong with the code, so the issue must be my workbook. I'm going to periodically assess - I remember seeing this issue once before (on a different workbook) an one day it just disappeared. I've already tried rebooting, but that didn't help. I also tried disabling all my add-ins, but that didn't do the trick either.  I really believe this is some kind of Excel bug.